# How do I set the default dictionary to a different language in Xiosis Scribe 2011

Tags: writing

I've downloaded some additional language packs for Scribe from the Xiosis website and installed them.

I know I can change them from the composer whenever I want. My question is how do I set the default dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to application settings in the desktop view in Scribe. In keyboard layouts and languages select the appropriate dictionary for left to right dictionary setting. That's all.